# How to Install Oracle Java7 in Ubuntu13.04

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, java

I am trying to install Java 7 in Ubuntu 13.04 using [this tutorial.](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-in-ubuntu-12-04.html)

> ### Preparing your system
>
> First you need to remove openjdk for this run the following command from your terminal
>   `sudo apt-get purge openjdk*`
>
> If you installed java 7 from any other PPA and you are having problem with java then you have to do following steps before installing the PPA menctioned here
>   
>   `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java7-installer*
>   sudo apt-get purge oracle-java7-installer*
>   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*java*
>   sudo apt-get update`
>
> ### Install Oracle Java 7 in Ubuntu 13.04/12.10/12.04
>
> Open the terminal and run the following commands
>
> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer`

All goes well until I reach the point:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Then I just get the error message

```
E: Unable to locate package oracle-java7-installer
```

What is the problem that is causing this?

Comment: Did you add `ppa` for `oracle-java7-installer` package successfully?

Comment: 13.04 is end of life. You can add the PPA from bobberson012 but you really should upgrade.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You first have to add the WebUPD8 repository to your system:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

*Then* install the package `oracle-java7-installer`.

If you already added the repository to your system, it could be you just never performed a `sudo apt-get update`, to update the package list.

Another option is `OpenJDK`.

Comment: The tutorial am using has it. http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-in-ubuntu-12-04.html

Comment: That is the tutorial he referred to.

Comment: See sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java and
sudo apt-get update is already in the tutorial and its not working. I still get the error.

Comment: You already ran `sudo apt-get purge openjdk*`, right?

Comment: Also, can I ask why you want to use `Oracle Java 7` instead of `OpenJDK`?

Comment: I have used `OpenJDK` instead, and its working. Good advice, Thanks!.

Comment: I am getting ERROR 'webupd8team' user ot team does not exist

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to resort to OpenJDK, you can just use a different Ubuntu version in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list` file:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu quantal main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu quantal main
```

Instead of "quantal" you can probably use any of the values from the drop-down list named "Published in:" on the [WebUPD8 team page](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java). I'm on "raring" which is not available directly, but this works perfectly.

Rationale: the installers provided by WebUPD8team simply download and run the official Java installer from Oracle, which is the same for all versions of Ubuntu (currently anyway). Therefore it does not matter which "installer installer" you really use.